# Strange google bot attack (e.g. /123456-12345678-123abc)

Tags: wordpress, googlebot

An abandoned outdated wordpress website that i thought the internet didn't know about got hacked. The attack got resolved quickly and had no real damage as for as I know now. But it does give an opportunity to study the attack used.

One thing that caught my attention is an upload of a malicous sitemap.xml causing google to do many (250k/day) requests to strange urls matching a specific pattern. 6 digits - 8 digits - 6 char hex

Examples:

```
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:13 +0200] "GET /035742-41258563-3329f7 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:13 +0200] "GET /042913-72193084-e8a20a HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:14 +0200] "GET /012527-34165946-30e419 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:14 +0200] "GET /064248-52623737-8691d5 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.2 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:15 +0200] "GET /052839-44405924-68722a HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.2 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:15 +0200] "GET /065830-65437791-de5b61 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:16 +0200] "GET /013227-70693694-023293 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:16 +0200] "GET /125539-43521853-8481a2 HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:17 +0200] "GET /033515-14477539-24816a HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.76.33 - - [03/Oct/2018:14:12:17 +0200] "GET /104450-28458335-28053c HTTP/1.1" 302 244 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I've verified it's a real google bot by using [host and ping](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html). I'm curious if anyone has seen this attack before and how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Never seen the attack before but it's execution is pretty simple: upload a massive sitemap of randomly generated "page urls" and let google do the rest.

Google will go "ooh look at that they must have added loads of new content, I want that" and will hit the site a LOT to try and get it, hence crippling the site. We see this when taking large sites to a new url structure all the time.

The only way I've found to compensate is to use NGINX rate limiting to stop any single IP making too many requests per second.